# В последнем посте, остается ссылка на следующий пост, и ведет она на него же. wordpress

Tags: wordpress

С помощью этого кода, ссылка ведет на последний пост. Но, как говорил в заголовке, на последнем посте эта ссылка тоже присутствует и ведет на этот же последний пост.

```
<a class="button " href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(true, '', false)->ID)?>">Следующий проект</a>
```

Я хочу, чтобы на последнем посте ссылки не было и наиболее логичным кажется делать это с помощью функции, которая, в случае, если следующего поста нет (пост последний) возвращала бы "" (ничего/null/0/false, в общем, чтобы проверить в условии).
Буду признателен за подсказки, возможно, идеи реализации по другой логике данной задумки. Благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, как-то так:

```
<?php 
$next_post = get_next_post(true);
if($next_post) : ?>
    <a class="button" href="<?php the_permalink($next_post); ?>">Следующий проект</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Вероятно, но, почему-то это не работает (

Comment: @igor добавил ещё один вариант.

Comment: @Igor должно работать, покажите код вашего цикла

Comment: @ДенисЯнчевский, спасибо! Вот теперь все работает!